# Kronecker product equality $(W \otimes W)^\top(W \otimes W)$

Tags: matrices, orthogonal-matrices, block-matrices, kronecker-product

Let $W = [W_1,W_2,W_3]^\top$ where $W_1,W_2,W_3 \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$. My question is if $(W \otimes W)^\top(W \otimes W)$ is the same as

$$
\left[ \begin{array}{c c}
W_1^\top \otimes W_1^\top& W_1^\top \otimes W_2^\top& W_1^\top \otimes W_3^\top& W_2^\top \otimes W_1^\top& W_2^\top \otimes W_2^\top& W_2^\top \otimes W_3^\top& W_3^\top \otimes W_1^\top& W_3^\top \otimes W_2^\top& W_3^\top \otimes W_3^\top \end{array} \right]
\left[ \begin{array}{c c}
W_1 \otimes W_1 \\
W_1 \otimes W_2 \\
W_1 \otimes W_3 \\
W_2 \otimes W_1 \\
W_2 \otimes W_2 \\
W_2 \otimes W_3 \\
W_3 \otimes W_1 \\
W_3 \otimes W_2 \\
W_3 \otimes W_3 \\
\end{array} \right] 
$$

My understanding is that this equality follows from the basic rules of the Kronecker product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the definition of the matrix $W$ note that
$$\eqalign{
W^TW
 &= \Big[\matrix{W_1&W_2&W_3}\Big]\cdot\left[\matrix{W_1^T\\W_2^T\\W_3^T}\right] \\
 &= \Big(W_1W_1^T + W_2W_2^T + W_3W_3^T\Big) \\&= \sum_{i=1}^3W_iW_i^T \\
}$$
Expanding the Kronecker expression in question yields
$$\eqalign{
\big(W\otimes W\big)^T\big(W\otimes W\big)
 &= \left(W^T\otimes W^T\right)\big(W\otimes W\big) \\&= W^TW\otimes W^TW \\
 &= \sum_{i=1}^3\sum_{j=1}^3W_iW_i^T\otimes W_jW_j^T \\
}$$
and expanding the sums leads to $9$ terms like $\;W_2W_2^T\otimes W_3W_3^T$

Comment: In my case, $W^\top W = Id$ and both expressions also give me the identity